# Why is u-boot ignoring my IF statement in uEnv.txt

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot

I already searched the web but couldn't find an answer, so I'm trying my luck here as a last hope.
I have a BeagleBone Black and want to boot from MMC no matter an SD-Card is inserted or not. 
Without an SD inserted the MMC is /dev/mmcblk0
The problem is that with an SD inserted the MMC becomes /dev/mmcblk1.
my original uEnv.txt looks like this.

```
uname_r=4.1.36-bone24
dtb=am335x-boneblack-emmc-overlay.dtb
optargs="consoleblank=0"
```

If an SD-Card is inserted it boots fine with /dev/mmcblk1p2.
If no SD-Card is inserted it still tries to boot from /dev/mmcblk1p2 but can't because MMC becomes /dev/mmcblk0.

My uEnv.txt for booting without an SD Card looks like this and it is possible to boot from MMC.

```
uname_r=4.1.36-bone24
dtb=am335x-boneblack-emmc-overlay.dtb
optargs="consoleblank=0"
mmcdev=0
mmcpart=2
```

Now I tried to but an If Else Statement into uEnv.txt as I found by my research on the Web.

```
uname_r=4.1.36-bone24
dtb=am335x-boneblack-emmc-overlay.dtb
optargs="consoleblank=0"
mmcdev=0 //this gets executed because root changes from /dev/mmcblk1p2 to /dev/mmcblk0p2
if mmc rescan; then mmcdev=1;fi
mmcpart=2
```

But it seems that this IF statement does not affect at all. But I know that uEnv.txt is read otherwise it wouldn't try to start from /dev/mmcblk0p2.

How can I achieve that the BBB is always booting from MMC with or without an SD-Card inserted?

Here is the u-boot Debug output with the last uEnv.txt without an SD Card inserted.

```
U-Boot 2016.03-dirty (Oct 03 2019 - 12:55:58 +0200)

       Watchdog enabled
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  512 MiB
Reset Source: Power-on reset has occurred.
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
Using default environment

Net:   <ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
Could not get PHY for cpsw: addr 0
cpsw, usb_ether
Press SPACE to abort autoboot in 2 seconds
Card did not respond to voltage select!
gpio: pin 56 (gpio 56) value is 0
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 0
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 0
gpio: pin 53 (gpio 53) value is 1
Card did not respond to voltage select!
Card did not respond to voltage select!
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc1(part 0) is current device
Scanning mmc 1:1...
gpio: pin 56 (gpio 56) value is 0
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 0
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 0
gpio: pin 53 (gpio 53) value is 1
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc1(part 0) is current device
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 1
Checking for: /uEnv.txt ...
Checking for: /boot.scr ...
Checking for: /boot/boot.scr ...
Checking for: /boot/uEnv.txt ...
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 1
136 bytes read in 19 ms (6.8 KiB/s)
Loaded environment from /boot/uEnv.txt
debug: [dtb=am335x-boneblack-emmc-overlay.dtb] ...
Using: dtb=am335x-boneblack-emmc-overlay.dtb ...
Checking if uname_r is set in /boot/uEnv.txt...
gpio: pin 56 (gpio 56) value is 1
Running uname_boot ...
loading /boot/vmlinuz-4.1.36-bone24 ...
6383816 bytes read in 373 ms (16.3 MiB/s)
loading /boot/dtbs/4.1.36-bone24/am335x-boneblack-emmc-overlay.dtb ...
53230 bytes read in 45 ms (1.1 MiB/s)
debug: [console=ttyO0,115200n8 consoleblank=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro rootfstype=ext4 rootwait] ...
debug: [bootz 0x82000000 - 0x88000000] ...
Kernel image @ 0x82000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x6168c8 ]
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 88000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x88000000
   Loading Device Tree to 8fff0000, end 8fffffed ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

Here is the u-boot Debug output with the last uEnv.txt an SD Card inserted.

```
U-Boot 2016.03-dirty (Oct 12 2016 - 15:19:30 +0200)

       Watchdog enabled
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  512 MiB
Reset Source: Global warm SW reset has occurred.
Reset Source: Power-on reset has occurred.
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
Using default environment

Net:   <ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
Could not get PHY for cpsw: addr 0
cpsw, usb_ether
Press SPACE to abort autoboot in 2 seconds
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc 0:1...
gpio: pin 56 (gpio 56) value is 0
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 0
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 0
gpio: pin 53 (gpio 53) value is 1
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 1
Checking for: /uEnv.txt ...
Checking for: /boot.scr ...
Checking for: /boot/boot.scr ...
Checking for: /boot/uEnv.txt ...
** Invalid partition 2 **
** Invalid partition 3 **
** Invalid partition 4 **
** Invalid partition 5 **
** Invalid partition 6 **
** Invalid partition 7 **
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc1(part 0) is current device
Scanning mmc 1:1...
gpio: pin 56 (gpio 56) value is 0
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 0
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 0
gpio: pin 53 (gpio 53) value is 1
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc1(part 0) is current device
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 1
Checking for: /uEnv.txt ...
Checking for: /boot.scr ...
Checking for: /boot/boot.scr ...
Checking for: /boot/uEnv.txt ...
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 1
136 bytes read in 19 ms (6.8 KiB/s)
Loaded environment from /boot/uEnv.txt
debug: [dtb=am335x-boneblack-emmc-overlay.dtb] ...
Using: dtb=am335x-boneblack-emmc-overlay.dtb ...
Checking if uname_r is set in /boot/uEnv.txt...
gpio: pin 56 (gpio 56) value is 1
Running uname_boot ...
loading /boot/vmlinuz-4.1.36-bone24 ...
6383816 bytes read in 372 ms (16.4 MiB/s)
loading /boot/dtbs/4.1.36-bone24/am335x-boneblack-emmc-overlay.dtb ...
53230 bytes read in 44 ms (1.2 MiB/s)
debug: [console=ttyO0,115200n8 consoleblank=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro rootfstype=ext4 rootwait] ...
debug: [bootz 0x82000000 - 0x88000000] ...
Kernel image @ 0x82000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x6168c8 ]
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 88000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x88000000
   Loading Device Tree to 8fff0000, end 8fffffed ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

The main difference is that I have a lot of "Invalid partitions" and that uEnv.txt is read out twice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `uEnv.txt` is not a shell script that is executed verbatim.  The relevant section of [include/environment/ti/mmc.h](https://gitlab.denx.de/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/include/environment/ti/mmc.h) looks like:

```
        "bootenvfile=uEnv.txt\0" \
        "importbootenv=echo Importing environment from mmc${mmcdev} ...; " \
                "env import -t ${loadaddr} ${filesize}\0" \
        "loadbootenv=fatload mmc ${mmcdev} ${loadaddr} ${bootenvfile}\0" \
        "loadimage=load ${devtype} ${bootpart} ${loadaddr} ${bootdir}/${bootfile}\0" \
        "loadfdt=load ${devtype} ${bootpart} ${fdtaddr} ${bootdir}/${fdtfile}\0" \
        "envboot=mmc dev ${mmcdev}; " \
                "if mmc rescan; then " \
                        "echo SD/MMC found on device ${mmcdev};" \
                        "if run loadbootscript; then " \
                                "run bootscript;" \
                        "else " \
                                "if run loadbootenv; then " \
                                        "echo Loaded env from ${bootenvfile};" \
                                        "run importbootenv;" \
                                "fi;" \
                                "if test -n $uenvcmd; then " \
                                        "echo Running uenvcmd ...;" \
                                        "run uenvcmd;" \
                                "fi;" \
                        "fi;" \
                "fi;\0" \
```

So we look for and load `uEnv.txt` in to memory and then import that in to the environment.  If we have a `uenvcmd` defined in the environment (which by convention won't have existed before now) we will then run it.  Your if/else needs to be handled in something like:

```
uenvcmd=if mmc rescan;mmcdev=1;fi
```

All of that said, that's not an answer to your actual problem.  To solve your actual problem you need to not pass `root=/dev/mmcblk...` to Linux as that's not stable but instead `root=PARTUUID=....` as that will be stable and a modern U-Boot (and environment) will figure that value out for you and pass it.